# Erro: Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" framework

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Depois de ter atualizado o Visual Studio para a versão 15.7.1 a seguinte mensagem começou a aparecer nos meus projetos prontos:

> Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1"
>   framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" in the
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet
>   restore

Se crio um projeto novo isso não acontece, gostaria de saber como poderia resolver, não consegui.

Já tentei Limpar/Restaurar solução e Restaurar Pacotes NuGet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depois de bastante testes resolvi da seguinte maneira: Fui no Gerenciador de Soluções -> Botão direito do mouse em NomedoProjeto.Android -> Propriedades -> Aplicativo -> Selecionei o "Android 8.1 (Oreo)" (Antes estava "Usar a Plataforma Mais Recente (Android 8.1 (Oreo))"). Segue as imagens para facilitar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A solução em si talvez não tenha sido mudar de `Usar a Plataforma Mais Recente (Android 8.1 (Oreo))` para `Android 8.1 (Oreo)`, mas sim o fato de ter havido uma alteração nos arquivos referentes ao projeto (arquivo `.csproj`) que deve ter forçado atualizar alguma outra informação importante para o compilador e que não visível. Entendo que tenha sido um bug do processo de atualização do VS com relação a projetos preexistentes.